# Replacing movie15 with media9 in powerdot presentations

Tags: movie15, ps2pdf, powerdot

Last year, I could make [`movie15`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/movie15) work in my [`powerdot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) presentations, through the `dvi2ps ps2pdf` route.  I re-visited recently and could not get the movies (`*.wma`) to appear anymore.  I spent the better part of two days trying to understand [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) as its replacement, and I can get the two to work independently, but not together (At least not real, pretty like).  Has anyone successfully accomplished this, or is there a reason this will probably not work?

I converted my WMA to MP4, and if I go the `dvipdf` route, using `media9` in either an article class or a `powerdot` class, I get the movie to show up correctly, however, while the article class "looks" right, the `powerdot` class PDF only covers the bottom 1/4 of the pdf page.

If I go the `dvi2ps` and `ps2pdf` (GS 9.05) the `powerdot` and the article class both look right (takes the entire page), but the movie doesn't show up in either one.  I can post specifics, but I thought I would get the big picture answer that it is indeed possible. I've tried most of the suggestions I have found (i.e. `-dNOSAFER`), but no luck!

**Response to Alexander:**
Excellent, at least now I know someone has it working and its just a matter of the right format/order of 1s and 0s.  I have a pretty similar setup, and when I ran your code, I got a:

```
'powerdot-default.ps' not found.
```

So I added a style option:

```
\documentclass[style=simple]{powerdot}
```

and then got the error:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet.
```

So I added: `\documentclass[style=simple, language=english]{powerdot}...`
(Just in case anyone receives these errors, a work around for me until I find the right problem).

Finally I got a `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` not found, probably because I do not have it installed (did it come with v0.3?) I just have the original `VPlayer.swf`.  So I will try and find `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` since I am still in the same boat, the PDF looks great (formating wise), but the movie still is not there... do I have to manually update to v0.3? I thought I was setup for automatic updating, but maybe not.

Could I ask what your switches/parameters are for `dvi2ps` and `ps2pdf`?

Comment: `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` is included in `media9` since yesterday. If you use TeXLive, try an update (`tlmgr update --all`). It may take a day for updates to be propagated to the mirrors. The second error is due to `babel`. Delete `*.aux` to make it go away and recompile. The first error doesn't have to do with `media9`, no idea what might be the reason for it.

Comment: It's called `dvips` here. Don't use any option with it. The same for `ps2pdf`.

Comment: MiKTeX package updates usually happen only once per week, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use `movie15` any longer. Once you have all your video files converted to or rebuilt as `MP4`, `media9` should do. The example below using the `powerdot` class and `media9` (v0.3, uploaded yesterday) worked for me. The video file was copied from `$TEXMF/doc/latex/media9/files` into the working directory. `ps2pdf` option `-dNOSAFER` is not required with `media9`.

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} %media9.sty needs it, language doesn't matter
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Embedded video}

  \includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=200pt, height=150pt,
    addresource=random.mp4,
    flashvars={
       src=random.mp4
      &loop=true
    }
  ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}

\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, got the StrobeMediaPlayback.swf through the new package today and solved all my ills (as well as deleting the aux file!) for the dvips ps2pdf route.  Still not sure what is causing the powerdot-ps problem, but the work around is working so I am not bothered. Thanks, great product!!   Oh, and the dvi2ps term is from WinEdt (I was pulling hair out changing the options for the executable I just brain washed myself...) Thanks again.